# Keeping Time.now accuarate

Tags: ruby, time

I have this script:

```
T = Time.now

def warn(input)
  puts "[#{T.hour}:#{T.min}:#{T.sec}] #{input}"
end
```

If I run this through a loop:

```
5.times do
  warn("test")
end
```

it will output the following:

```
[22:24:49] test
[22:24:49] test
[22:24:49] test
[22:24:49] test
[22:24:49] test
```

I would like the time to be constantly updated, for example:

```
[22:24:49] test
[22:24:50] test
[22:24:51] test
[22:24:52] test
[22:24:53] test
```

How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By generating the time each time.

```
def warn(input)
  t = Time.now
  puts "[#{t.hour}:#{t.min}:#{t.sec}] #{input}"
end
```

Comment: That works but now when the time is less then 10 it only shows one number instead of a 01, 02, 03, etc.. Example: `[22:24:59] test`
;`[22:24:0] test`
;`[22:24:1] test`;
`[22:24:2] test`
;`[22:24:3] test`

Comment: So is there a way around that?

Comment: @13aal If you want to ask a different question, ask a new question.

Comment: Using sawa's redefinition of `warn`, write `5.times { warn("test"); sleep 1 }`.

Comment: sawa, you haven't answered the question, which is stated in the last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

```
def warn(input)
  puts Time.now.strftime("[%H:%M:%S] #{input}")
end
```

[`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime).